# How to specify PHP version for composer docker container?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, composer-php

I have a composer container that looks like this;

docker-compose.yml

```
composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: infrastructure/composer.dockerfile
    container_name: client-composer
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: customuser
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - client
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM composer:1

RUN addgroup -g 1000 customuser && adduser -G customuser -g customuser -s /bin/sh -D customuser

RUN chown -R customuser:customuser /var/www/html

RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

How can I tell it to use PHP version 7.2 and not 8.0 which it currently uses?

Comment: Why is that relevant after all? Are you facing any problem with running Composer with PHP 8?

Comment: ...also, what do you want to achieve? Composer's container should be used to install dependencies, not for running your application

Comment: I'm putting an old project into a docker container and it's dependancies require PHP 7.2 or it throws some errors. We are in the process of updating the PHP version and dependancies however that is going to take longer. In the meantime I need to tell this composer container to use PHP 7.2

Comment: You can use the 1.10.16 if you're seeking general PHP version 7 compat. Otherwise the other recommendation for the precise version of 7.2 is to stitch together your own Dockerfile

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is there anything not working? Are you facing any specific error message?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I have specified composer version 1 but it uses php 8

Comment: @NicoHaase the errors are to do with private repos and is irrelevant, all I need to know is how to tell a composer container which php version to use. not to bugfix the dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

Composer has moved on to PHP 8 and that's what included in the composer Docker image.

You can try to fetch the Composer docker file from right before they made the move to PHP 8 and build an image from that. Do note that you'll be missing all updates since then, though.

The old Dockerfile is here: https://github.com/composer/docker/blob/582c6f4e10b6b8fbf9bc1c5b02d6ec24694fe8d4/1.10/Dockerfile

If you want to browse the history of the Dockerfile to see what changes have been made, you can see it here: https://github.com/composer/docker/commits/890a12899ba8fbd4876bb8513d5cb75ce68d230c/1.10/Dockerfile

Another option is to take the current Composer Dockerfile and simply changing it to be based on `php:7-alpine` rather than `php:8-alpine`. It might work and it might not. The current version is here: https://github.com/composer/docker/blob/890a12899ba8fbd4876bb8513d5cb75ce68d230c/1.10/Dockerfile

Comment: Hi Hans thanks for the answer, is there anyway I can tell the composer in the dockerfile or yml which php version to use instead of putting composer inside a PHP container?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In your Dockerfile you base your own image on `composer:1`. That image is made using the Dockerfile in the last link in my answer. As you can see in that Dockerfile, it is based on `php:8-alpine`. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a composer image available on Docker Hub that's based on PHP 7. They're all PHP 8 now.

Comment: @Aaron I tried cloning the GitHub repository and changing their Dockerfile to be based on `php:7-alpine`. The image builds ok with that change, but I have no way of checking if it actually works.