# Dockerizing Magento 2.4.3-p2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, docker, nginx, magento, cicd

I have been trying to Dockerizing Magento 2.4.3-p2 on my Ubuntu 22.04. So here is my

```
`docker-compose.yml
version: '3.0'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    restart: always

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html 
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.13
    ports:
     - 3300:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
      - MYSQL_USER=magento
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=magento
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - php-fpm

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node

  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"

  varnish:
    image: varnish:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - nginx

  composer:
    image: composer:2.3
    volumes:
      - ./magento:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html



volumes:
  dbdata:`
```

`nginx dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine-perl

ARG APP_ID=1000

RUN addgroup -g "$APP_ID" app \
 && adduser -G app -u "$APP_ID" -h /var/www/html -s /bin/bash -S app
RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid
RUN mkdir /sock

USER app:app

VOLUME /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html`
```

`Nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name loaclhost

    root /var/www/html; # Magento root directory

    index index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000; # Connect to PHP-FPM container
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Php dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.0-fpm-buster

ARG APP_ID=1000
RUN groupadd -g "$APP_ID" app \
  && useradd -g "$APP_ID" -u "$APP_ID" -d /var/www/html -s /bin/bash app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    unzip \
    git \
    nano \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp --with-xpm \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) xsl \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) soap \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) sockets

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]

WORKDIR /var/www/html`
```

I run each container indiuvally and checked them. But when I'm running
`sudo docker run --rm -it --volume $(pwd)/src:/var/www/html composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p2 . --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl`

To install the Magento locally. I'm getting an error.

`Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p2]. - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p2 requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your php version (8.2.10) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Although I am clearly using php:7.4.0-fpm-buster in my setup. To avoid the confit I have purged PHP from my local machine as well. What should I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can resolve the error of not matching the PHP platform version for your containerized composer invocation.

Answering to the initial composer project configuration creation statement in your question I was able to find (`composer create-project`) adding the `--ignore-platform-reqs` command line argument should prevent the error message.

In general what is going on is that when you call composer containerized, it is using the container-configured PHP version (8.2.10) and is not using a different (the expected, more aged 7.x PHP version) that may be in a different container, but is out of scope for composer to detect, as Composer has been containerized, and with that level of isolation, any different than the containerized PHP version is out of reach for composer and can not be inferred **from within the container environment**.

However, there are both command-line arguments/environment parameters and composer.json project (and perhaps even global) configuration settings, that may allow you to make use of to command Composer to not rely on inference but instead stick to your commandment and/or configuration for the PHP version and any other platform package (and perhaps a bit out of scope in regard of your question: also any project package).

Please see the Composer documentation for all composer command-line arguments, environment parameters (often called environment variables), the whole composer.json schema and last but not least all configuration and options.

Also you may want to follow the pattern of a build container with a multi-stage build that is using the production version of PHP you target as your platform version, copies composer.phar (or its equivalent executable) into the containerized build environment, creates the project there and then, finally, copies from that stage the actual result into the final image where you'd like to prepare the mount. Mind thought you're matching the mount strategy you're trying to do here, because depending on the kind of mind and order to mount, you may require to apply a file copy operation (e.g. prepared in a tarball) *after* mounting.

The docker-compose.yml based configuration should provide you all the options despite which build pattern you're trying to follow, even if you use a little dated docker version, just take care you're able to use docker compose V2.

For Composer and PHP keep the containerization in mind, that is, `docker run` will always be within it's own container and can only be what the image of it provides.

Comment: Ok. I got the issue that might be but still have no idea how to fix it. Din't face any such problem with other PHP applications like Laravel or Wordpress but it's only in Magento.

Comment: @drakpasanger: I see. Could you share your expectation a bit more? E.g. when do you intend to execute the composer create-project in the project lifecycle (after clean git checkout?) BTW. Laravel and Wordpress likely won't complain because Laravel supports 8.2.x (if it even has the required platform version limited upwards) and Wordpress is not a Composer project at all. And perhaps if you could comment what kind of example would help you based on your current understanding, then I could check if I can make certain things more exemplary with the answer. Did you ty the command-line argument?

Comment: I have a simple requirement to develop a CD/CI cycle for Magento ver 2.4.3-p2 which uses PHP 7.4.0 and cannot update the live project because of underlying extension issues. In the project lifecycle to keep it simple first run `docker compose and then check that all the necessary containers are up and running I run `composer create-project`. I have a basic understanding of docker and not much about Magento which I am learning right now which might be the knowledge gap I am facing I used https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento for references but found it a bit overwhelming.

Comment: sorry didn't get your last comment.

Comment: I commented, then deleted and then put that comment in case you saw the deleted one. You can ignore it. But while we're here: Do you really need the _composer_ service in the docker-compose.yml? From what I can see, the _php-fpm_ container is already configured as build container as it includes composer. Only the project mount differs ./src (php-fpm) vs. ./magento (composer). Can you elaborate on the differences? Could it be the different project mount points are in error (e.g. it should always be the same)?

Comment: I added the composer container just in case for future to add the authentication key and password of Magento in `.env` so it will be easy to share and deploy also thought that a running composer container would help it faster for installing dependencies and extensions in future. But it might be the reason for the error can always use the php-fpm composer only.

Comment: If you really need the composer container and given you also need php 7, you can use the old composer 1.10 container.  It's discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269028/how-to-specify-php-version-for-composer-docker-container

Comment: Actually as suggested in my answer, using `--ignore-platform-reqs` should already solve this. Otherwise similar to providing Composers authentication credentials for the Magento repository for the specific _composer_ service container, it should also be possible to configure that container specifying the exact same platform version. Additionally I think using the _php-fpm_ service container is also an option as it contains Composer as well. However I do not see any reason not using the _composer_ service container, just to be explicit about that, let me chew on an update of the answer.

Comment: I checked by removing the `composer` container and checking for the 'php-fmp' container 'docker exec -it {pgp-fpm-conatiner} composer -v`  it output `Composer version 2.6.4`. I guess that might be causing the issue will try to see if I can use an older version of `composer` which will be more compatible with `php-7.5`. I saw many `composer` images on the docker hub and most of them are using `php-8.0'.

Comment: @drakpasanger: I get it running here, the important part is to use `docker compose exec` (or `docker compose run`) then you can use the service name directly. For the composer container you need to use the `--ignore-platform-reqs` because the PHP version in the _composer_ container is different. Sorry, had no time to update the answer so far with verbatim examples. I might be able tonight. This is per your requirements to first run `docker compose up -d` and then `docker compose exec php-fpm composer create-project`. Your reasoning yesterday about the `composer` container makes sense.... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) ... to me, I was thinking about giving an example with it and how you can have the platform configuration within ./docker/composer as you can't fully provide it with `.env` for Composer.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the update it's working but just facing 2 main issues. 1st the Nginx container keeps on quitting which might be due to some issue with `conf.d` file and I will look into it but 2nd while using `docker exec -it {php-fpm-container} composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p2 . --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` I cannot mount the volume of `./src` with `var/www/html` any solution for that?

Comment: Why can't you mount the volume? Because it contains files and composer create-project requires an empty directory? Then replace `.` with `composer-magento-project`  if such directory does not exists. Otherwise you have to share why you considered to create a new project with composer in a non-empty directory. For a build test if composer create-project works (as you has previously commented), using an empty directory should suffice to proof the build container (php-fpm in your project) should suffice. Please share more info.

Comment: @hakre the requirement is simple I want an `./src` from the host machine to be mounted with and `var/www/html` so I can make changes in the `./src` which can be reflected instantly and later copied in dockerfile for the migration. But with the above command `composer project` is downloding the source code but it's not getting in the `./src` folder even by changing `.` to `./src`. Which is an empty folder as mentioned earlier. Sorry I am not able to get it a bit new to docker and volumes are confusing a bit.

Comment: @drakpasanger is `./src` empty? If it is for `var/www/html` which represents a public folder  for hosting, it should normally *not* be the projects' root directory, e.g. the one where a `composer.json` file is placed. This is different from Magento1, Wordpress and similar aged project setups, cf. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/103814/4115. Apart from that, with the `composer create-project` command you (only) create a new project, that is when you already write about making changes into `./src` and all you want to do to initially setup/initialize Magento there, use the `php-fpm` ... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) container. It not only has Composer in it, but also you have the _app_ user (uid/gid 1000), that is when you run with that user (given `docker compose up -d`, then `docker compose exec --user app -it /bin/bash`), you should be able to execute all the things you need. During CI, run `composer install` in that container, as you have comitted the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file already therein. Then no more `composer create-project` run is necessary. HTH. The `php-fpm` service is also your build container.

Comment: Yes `./src` is an empty folder where I want to edit the code and then I can compile it in the `php-fpm`  container that part I got. But as mentioned earlier was trying to mount the volume of `./src` to the inside of the container `/var/www/html` to make development easy and fast. `docker exec -it {php-fpm-container} composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p2 ./src --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` but even after completion of the process successfully the `./src` folder is empty.

Comment: given `./src` is empty, the only issue with the configuration shared in your project is, that it is also set-up as COMPOSER_HOME in the `php-fpm` service. That is, the moment a Composer runs in the the container, it will create directory entries there (e.g. the cache directory). Unless COMPOSER_HOME is not changed, you may still see an error that the directory is not empty despite it initially was. Why the folder is empty on your system I have no clue, this is not the case on my end. It is important that you run it with the mount/volume during install, not only afterwards.

Comment: This is what I meant in the answer that you may have a workflow that requires to copy files for the way you do it. E.g. different mounts (magento vs. src) but also what you desribe with the empty src folder: first install but not mount, then mount and the mount hides the directory content unless you unmount. Therefore you need to copy, then mount and then copy again or first mount and only then create the project.

Comment: "Therefore you need to copy, then mount and then copy again or first mount and only then create the project. " Can you kindly elaborate on this one? Honestly, right now I haven't decided on workflow; I am just trying to make this Magento local development plan is to figure out that later depending on what end conf. look turns out to be at the end. It has already been 12 weeks since I am working on it and I haven't got any closer.

Comment: I'd suggest that you have the mount active while you create the project therein. See how Docker handles file system data in https://docs.docker.com/storage/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running composer in the composer container, not the php `Dockerfile` you created.

To break this down:

```bash
sudo docker run --rm -it --volume $(pwd)/src:/var/www/html composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p2 . --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl

docker run \ # the command
--rm -it \   # remove container after use and run with interactive mode
--volume $(pwd)/src:/var/www/html \ # mount $(pwd)/src into container
composer \   # the image you are running
create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p2 . --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl # the command you are wanting to run in the composer image
```

So that will run using the version of PHP in the composer container, not the one in your `Dockerfile`

To try and fix this, as you are installing composer into your docker image, I would replace the composer service with a PHP service in your `docker-compose.yaml` and then use `docker compose run php-service-name create-project ...` to run the composer command with the correct version of PHP and dependencies.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand you completely. Can you kindly elaborate? To solve an issue I have tried not using the Composer in the yml file and directly running it via `php-fpm` container but somehow the same issue.