# Not able to compile .less Magento 2.4.6-p2

Tags: magento, compilation, gruntjs, less

I have a local Magento Cloud 2.4.6-p2 + Docker, local site runs perfect without errors, Im trying to customize the Magento Luma Theme, i created my own custom theme parent from Luma, grunt installed and working.

In order to compile my customizations I use grunt:

grunt clean

Execution Time (2023-09-28 18:14:48 UTC-0)
loading tasks      187ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8%
clean:var          801ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 36%
clean:pub          698ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 31%
clean:generation   324ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 14%
clean:blank         24ms  ▇▇ 1%
clean:soscode2cap  120ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 5%
clean:backend       43ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
Total 2.3s
`(No problems found)`

grunt exec

Execution Time (2023-09-28 18:16:18 UTC-0)
exec:blank         2.5s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 10%
exec:luma          2.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 9%
exec:soscode2cap   2.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 9%
exec:backend       5.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 23%
exec:all          12.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 49%
Total 25.2s
`(No problems found)`

grunt less

root@deploy:/app# grunt less
Running "less:blank" (less) task
`>> pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_reset.less: [L7:C4] Error evaluating function` unit`: the first argument to unit must be a number. Have you forgotten parenthesis? Warning: Error compiling pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.less Use --force to continue.`

Aborted due to warnings.

Here is the problem, I try to check for _reset.less file under: pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_reset.less *i can see the file in Visual Studio Code, but when i try to opened i get this message: Unable to open '_reset.less' file not found. Options: Cancel / Create File.

If i select **Create** i get this message: Unable to create file '/Users/alex/Documents/GARDEA/magento-cloud-gardea/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_reset.less' that already exists when overwrite flag is not set.

I already try, deploying, also rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/_requirejs/* generated/code/*

UPDATE: Fix, it was a mistake I made during installation.

Comment: Can you please help me with setting up Magento Cloud 2.4.6-p2 + Docker, been struggling with it for quite some time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163680/dockerizing-magento-2-4-3-p2-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Sure, follow this steps: